# Is there a way to find out what's left to render?

Tags: layout, blocks

just wondering if there was a function that displays what blocks are left to render in a page.

Doing `$this->getChildHtml();` renders all child html blocks that haven't yet been rendered but how do I find out what's left to render and call those blocks individually?

I tried a `var_dump` on `this->getChildHtml();` but it just outputted a string of the html of the blocks.

Is there a way to maybe do something like:

```
<?php
    foreach ($this->getChildHtml() as $_child) {
        var_dump($_child);
        print_r($_child->getData());
    }
?>
```

it doesn't return any data but my point is more is there a way to call information per child?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the child blocks of a block, $this refer to the current block of a template put below code in your left template file.

```
Zend_Debug::dump(array_keys($this->getChild()));
```